# Mi usuario nunca se loguea en php

Tags: php

Hola estoy intentando arreglar mi login porque a pesar de que me logueo siempre me muestra los mismos errores:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 20

Y tambien me da invalido:

> Password or username incorrect

La tabla tiene el siguiente aspecto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

login.php:

```
<?php
include 'inc/base.php';

function captcha() {
  $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
  $privatekey = '';
  $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".strip_tags($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  $data = json_decode($response);
  return isset($data->success) AND $data->success == true;
}

// LOGIN
if (isset($_POST['login'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb, id, username FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?');
    $query->execute([
      $_POST['username'],
      md5($_POST['password'])
    ]);
    $data = $query->fetch();
    if ($data->nb) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $data->username;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $data->id;
        header("location: index.php");
        exit;
    } else {
      $error = "Password or username incorrect";
    } 
}

// SIGNUp
if (isset($_POST['signup'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['confirm'])) {
  if (preg_match("#^[a-z0-9_-]{3,30}$#i", $_POST['username'])) {
      if (captcha()) {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb FROM users WHERE username=?");
    $query->execute([
      $_POST['username']
    ]);
    $data = $query->fetch();

    if (!$data->nb) {
      if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb FROM users WHERE email=?");
        $query->execute([
          $_POST['email']
        ]);
        $data = $query->fetch();

        if (!$data->nb) {
          if ($_POST['password'] === $_POST['confirm']) {
            if (strlen($_POST['password']) >= 4) {

              $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES(:username, :email, :password)");
              $query->execute([
                "username" => $_POST['username'],
                "email" => $_POST['email'],
                "password" => md5($_POST['password'])
              ]);

              $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
              $_SESSION['user_id'] = $db->lastInsertId();

              header("Location: index.php");
              exit;

            } else {
              $error = "The password must be at least 4 characters";
            }
          } else {
            $error = "The two passwords must match";
          }
        } else {
          $error = "This email is already taken";
        }
      } else {
        $error = "Incorrect email format";
      }
    } else {
      $error = "This username is already taken";
    }
  }
  else 
  {
      $error = "Invalid captcha";  
  }
  }
  else
  {
    $error = "The username must be within 3 and 30 characters";
  }
}

include 'inc/header.php';
?>
    <?php
    if (isset($error)) echo "<div class=\"message_erreur\">$error</div>";
    ?>
        <section>
            <h1 class="title">Log in</h1>
            <form method="POST">
            Username : <input type="text" name="username" required />
            Password : <input type="password" name="password" required />
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Se connecter" required />
        </form>
        </section>

        <section>
            <h2 class="title">Sign Up</h2>
            <form method="POST">
            <label>Username :<br />
              <input type="text" name="username" <?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) echo 'value="'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']).'"'; ?> required />
            </label>
            <label>Email :<br />
              <input type="text" name="email" <?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo 'value="'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']).'"'; ?> required />
            </label>
            <label>Password :<br />
              <input type="password" name="password" required />
            </label>
            <label>Repeat password :<br />
              <input type="password" name="confirm" required />
            </label>
            <center><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdXGA8TAAAAAKV0MvCvn5eT3--7v4eipyvKPD0s"></div></center><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Créer un compte" />
        </form>
        </section>
<?php
include 'inc/footer.php';
```

Comment: Considera eliminar las claves que expones en tu pregunta. `$privatekey...`, `data-sitekey=...`.

Answer (score 4):

El error es porque `$data = $query->fetch();` devuelve los registros en formato de array, **no** de objeto. Entonces, en la línea 20 debieras sustituir:

```
if ($data->nb) {
```

por

```
if ($data['nb']) {
```

(Fuente: [Manual de PHP: PDO::fetch](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php), parámetro *fetch_style*)

Comment: igualmente me pone Password or username incorrect cuando me logueo? el error ese si se corrigio pero al loguearme no reconoce el usuario cuando lo puse bien sabes porque pueda pasar eso?